# Header background Image does not change in all pages from cms

Tags: php, css, content-management-system

I'm using Couch CMS ,and  i made  the  header  background an editable region,then when  I change  the  image from the  admin page the  new  image  appear only in the  home  page although in the  other  pages  i use  this

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("header.php");  ?>
```

the  code  in index.php:

```
    <?php require_once('admin/cms.php'); ?>
    <cms:template title = 'English Home Page'>
    <cms:editable name='header' type='image' />
    </cms:template>
     <?php echo file_get_contents("header.php");  ?>
    <?php COUCH::invoke(); ?>
```

the  code in header.php

```
    <?php require_once( 'admin/cms.php' ); ?>
    .site-header {
        background-image: url("<cms:show header />");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-attachment: notdefined;
        background-clip: padding-box;
        background-size: cover;
        background-origin: padding-box;
    }

    <?php COUCH::invoke(); ?>
```

why when  i get the header  page contents  in other  pages except index the  image  does not  change??

Answer (score 0):

I think that You need to append Couch CMS's `cms:editable` to a regular html tag pair.

Like so:

```
<div class="header-bg" style="background-image: url('<cms:show header />');"></div>
```

You simply need to append a `style="background-image: url("<cms:show header />");"` to your main header container.

e.g.

`<cms:editable name='header' type='image' style='style="background-image: url("<cms:show header />");'/>`

Specify the rest of the CSS in your main styles file.

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need to use the 'header' as a full-fledged template (because I don't think it is supposed to be accessed directly through a browser using its URL).
Instead, it should be converted into a 'snippet' that can then be included in the other templates.

To do that, please create a text file named 'header.html' with the following contents and then place this file within the 'snippets' folder of your Couch installation (which appears to have been renamed as 'admin' in your case). Please note that no `<?php require_once('admin/cms.php'); ?>` or `<?php COUCH::invoke(); ?>` are required in snippets.

```
.site-header {
background-image: url("<cms:get_custom_field 'header' masterpage='index.php' />");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-attachment: notdefined;
background-clip: padding-box;
background-size: cover;
background-origin: padding-box;
}
```

Next, in all your templates where you wish to include the header, use the following statement

```
<cms:embed 'header.html' />
```

So, for example, your index.php template would now become this -

```
<?php require_once('admin/cms.php'); ?>
<cms:template title = 'English Home Page'>
    <cms:editable name='header' type='image' />
</cms:template>

<cms:embed 'header.html' />
<?php COUCH::invoke(); ?
```

Hope this helps.